# Swith to an iframe with protractor 3.x.x

Tags: angularjs, selenium, iframe, protractor, e2e-testing

I am trying to switch to an iframe in my e2e test.

My code is

```
var el = element(by.id('iframe-container')).element(by.tagName('iframe'));

browser.switchTo().frame(el);

$('.top-bar-right .btn-primary').click();

browser.switchTo().defaultContent();
```

For some reason this is not working, does someone knows if their is any change in the last versions of selenium/protractor.

I have selenium version 2.5.x and protractor version 3.1.x.

My test is buging giving me this error :

```
FATER ERROR: CALL_AND_RETRY_LAST Allocation failed - process out of memory
```

Thank you !

Comment: Can you check in chrome and firefox - same error in both browsers?

Comment: Yes same problem on both

Answer (score 0):

You can simply write like this:

```
browser.ignoreSynchronization=true;
      browser.switchTo().frame('iframe-container').then(function(){
          expect('something').not.toBeNull();
          $('.top-bar-right .btn-primary').click().then(function(){
              browser.switchTo().defaultContent().then(function(){
                  expect('something').not.toBeNull();
              });
          });
      });
```

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me.  My example is accessing the body element when testing TinyMCE.

```
var test = function(){
    var iframe = element(by.tagName('iframe'));

    // iframe doesn't have angular... 
    browser.ignoreSynchronization = true;

    // must enter the iframe with the WebElement? 
    // or it crashes with out of memory error!! 
    return browser.switchTo().frame(iframe.getWebElement())
          .then(function(){
              // in the iframe.. 
              var editor_body = element(by.tagName('body'));
              editor_body.sendKeys('test');
          })
          .then(function(){
              // restore sync for angular
              browser.ignoreSynchronization = false;
              return browser.switchTo().defaultContent();
          });
};
```